# authentication winform + asp

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I am building a desktop application that needs to update current user's status frequently. This status will be available as RSS feed.
In order to do this, I think I can create a asp.net folder and secure it using form authentication. When the desktop application written as winform in c# needs to update status, it can set WebRequest.Credentials and upload data.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms Authentication might be a little 'overkill' for what it sounds like you're trying to do. Consider writing a simple .NET web service, and using SoapAuthentication or even passing in some credentials (or an authentication token that your server recognises) as parameters to the web method. It depends on how important security is, and what kind of traffic you think your desktop application will generate.

It's difficult to be more specific without more details! :)